# echo session variable on ajax post call

Tags: php, ajax, session

I'm trying to echo session variable on ajax call
**without sending the variable in the post request (so it will be hidden and unchangable)**

this is my code

**first php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["check"] = "check";
?>
<script>
jQuery.post("https://check.com/ajax.php",{}, function(data,status)
{console.log("data")});
</script>
```

**second php:**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "SESSION: "
echo "<br>"
echo $_SESSION["check"];
```

I get the result without the session variable, like this:
SESSION:

(empty row insted of session variable row)

how can I make it work?

Comment: Do you have any output before `session_start()`? If yes, move session_start() to the top of the file, before any output (echo's, html, space, tab, line break or what ever) and see if there's any difference.

Comment: this is it! thank you!